How to make a whitelist of unlicensed players while online-mode is on?
I'm maintaining a small server for my friends. Most of my friends got official copies of Mincraft Java Edition, but One of my friend don't have one.
If I set online-mode to false, all of our Inventory and skin will lost. And I don't want prople to fake accounts.
Can I make my friend's UUID into some kind of whitelist, make him bypass online-mode?

You can't.
There's this very old project that tries to do that, but this isn't a thing that is supported by the vanilla software or any of the forks of Bukkit.
This is because:

When you play offline-mode=false, UUIDs are based off what Mojang reports (from the session handshake).
When you play offline-mode=true, UUIDs are based off a hash of the username.

That's all what switching offline-mode does.

Without drastically modifying the handshake protocols in the Minecraft server software, this isn't something you can do.
The closest to semi-online and offline mode we have is a server running Geyser and Floodgate, where your friend is playing through Bedrock Edition where anyone can have an "account" as long as they have a valid copy of the game as Floodgate removes the requirement of needing to feed Geyser a Minecraft Java account that exists.
(Note: If you have a server running Geyser only, anyone connecting using Bedrock edition will still need a valid Java account to play; for Floodgate, the UUID is a hash of the player's XID, but the first sixteen bytes are zeros).
